# SSRS - Using a Lookup in Background Color property changes the values of the entire row in the tablix

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-2016

I have a dataset that contains balances for customer accounts by month:

| CustomerID | Month | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 100.00 |
| 1 | 2/1/2022 | -100.00 |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 2/1/2022 | 100.00 |

I am then simply displaying this dataset in a table, so essentially just as it looks above.

I am trying to change the background color for balances which are canceled out by a negative balance of the exact same amount. So for Customer 1 for example, I would want to change the background color of the Balance cells for 1/1/2022 and 2/1/2022, since those cancel out. For my purposes, I am not worried about matching multiple times - if this customer also had a +-100.00 balance for 3/1/2022, it is fine for all three of those to be changed.

My expected output:

| CustomerID | Month | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | ***100.00*** |
| 1 | 2/1/2022 | ***-100.00*** |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 2/1/2022 | 100.00 |

I am using the following expression in the Background Color property to accomplish this:

```
=IIf(
    IsNothing(
        Lookup(
            (-1 * Fields!Balance.Value) & Fields!CustomerID.Value
            ,Fields!Balance.Value & Fields!CustomerID.Value
            ,Fields!Balance.Value
            ,"BalancesDS"
        )
    )
    ,"No Color"
    ,"Yellow"
)
```

The issue I am having with this is that when the expression finds a match, it changes the data displayed for that row. The actual output I am getting is this:

| CustomerID | Month | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | ***100.00*** |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | ***100.00*** |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 2/1/2022 | 100.00 |

Note how instead of showing 2/1/2022 with a balance of -100.00, it is being changed to essentially a duplicate of the 1/1/2022 row.

I do not have any other expressions on this report at the moment, all of the fields displayed in the table are just straight from the dataset, so I'm at a bit of a loss. Even more strangely, this only seems to happen when the cancelling rows are adjacent in the dataset. I have the dataset sorted by CustomerID, then Month. I was only able to find one occurrence of this in my dataset, but when there was a different month in between the matching months, the data was displayed correctly:

| CustomerID | Month | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | ***100.00*** |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | ***100.00*** |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 2/1/2022 | 100.00 |
| 3 | 1/1/2022 | ***100.00*** |
| 3 | 2/1/2022 | 200.00 |
| 3 | 3/1/2022 | ***-100.00*** |

See Customer 3 above. 1/1/2022 and 3/1/2022 cancel each other out, and with the extra month in between, the data is correctly displayed in this instance for whatever reason. Customer 1 is still displaying incorrectly though.

If I create an exact duplicate of the dataset with a different name and have the lookup look in that duplicate instead of in the tablix dataset, then I do get my expected output. So that is a workaround that I can use, but I would definitely prefer not to double the amount of data/datasets unless there is no alternative.

Does this seem to be working as intended? Is this even reproducible in a different environment? I'm at a bit of a loss, the expression and the report as a whole are pretty basic so I'm not really seeing any way to fix this other than by using a duplicate dataset.

Edit: Below is a sample RDL code, in case anyone feels like trying it. Had to remove some things like style properties for the tablixes to fit the character limit.

[image: image of sample]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily">
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <DataSourceReference>/Data Sources/Test</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>4e7acbfa-3ce2-4d8a-abdc-9d7414cafb67</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="BalancesDS">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>select
  cast(1 as int) as CustomerID
  ,cast('2022-01-01' as date) as MonthPeriod
  ,cast(100.00 as decimal(18, 2)) as Balance
union
select
  cast(1 as int) as CustomerID
  ,cast('2022-02-01' as date) as MonthPeriod
  ,cast(-100.00 as decimal(18, 2)) as Balance
union
select
  cast(2 as int) as CustomerID
  ,cast('2022-01-01' as date) as MonthPeriod
  ,cast(100.00 as decimal(18, 2)) as Balance
union
select
  cast(2 as int) as CustomerID
  ,cast('2022-02-01' as date) as MonthPeriod
  ,cast(100.00 as decimal(18, 2)) as Balance
union
select
  cast(3 as int) as CustomerID
  ,cast('2022-01-01' as date) as MonthPeriod
  ,cast(100.00 as decimal(18, 2)) as Balance
union
select
  cast(3 as int) as CustomerID
  ,cast('2022-02-01' as date) as MonthPeriod
  ,cast(200.00 as decimal(18, 2)) as Balance
union
select
  cast(3 as int) as CustomerID
  ,cast('2022-03-01' as date) as MonthPeriod
  ,cast(-100.00 as decimal(18, 2)) as Balance</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="CustomerID">
          <DataField>CustomerID</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="MonthPeriod">
          <DataField>MonthPeriod</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Balance">
          <DataField>Balance</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Decimal</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
            <TablixBody>
              <TablixColumns>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>1in</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>1in</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>1in</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
              </TablixColumns>
              <TablixRows>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox15">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>With BackgroundColor Expression</Value>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox15</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                        <ColSpan>3</ColSpan>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell />
                    <TablixCell />
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox6">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Customer ID</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox6</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox8">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Month Period</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox8</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox10">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Balance</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox10</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="CustomerID">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!CustomerID.Value</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>CustomerID</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="MonthPeriod">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!MonthPeriod.Value</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <Format>d</Format>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>MonthPeriod</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Balance">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!Balance.Value</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Balance</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <BackgroundColor>=IIf(
  IsNothing(
    Lookup(
      (-1 * Fields!Balance.Value) &amp; Fields!CustomerID.Value
      ,Fields!Balance.Value &amp; Fields!CustomerID.Value
      ,Fields!Balance.Value
      ,"BalancesDS"
    )
  )
  ,"No Color"
  ,"Yellow"
)</BackgroundColor>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
              </TablixRows>
            </TablixBody>
            <TablixColumnHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixColumnHierarchy>
            <TablixRowHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                </TablixMember>
                <TablixMember>
                  <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                </TablixMember>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="Details" />
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixRowHierarchy>
            <DataSetName>BalancesDS</DataSetName>
            <Top>0.25in</Top>
            <Left>0.25in</Left>
            <Height>0.75in</Height>
            <Width>3in</Width>
          </Tablix>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix2">
            <TablixBody>
              <TablixColumns>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>1in</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>1in</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>1in</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
              </TablixColumns>
              <TablixRows>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox16">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Without BackgroundColor Expression</Value>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox15</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                        <ColSpan>3</ColSpan>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell />
                    <TablixCell />
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox7">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Customer ID</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox6</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox9">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Month Period</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox8</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox11">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Balance</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox10</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="CustomerID2">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!CustomerID.Value</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>CustomerID</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="MonthPeriod2">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!MonthPeriod.Value</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <Format>d</Format>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>MonthPeriod</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Balance2">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!Balance.Value</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Balance</rd:DefaultName>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
              </TablixRows>
            </TablixBody>
            <TablixColumnHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixColumnHierarchy>
            <TablixRowHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                </TablixMember>
                <TablixMember>
                  <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                </TablixMember>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="Details2" />
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixRowHierarchy>
            <DataSetName>BalancesDS</DataSetName>
            <Top>1.5in</Top>
            <Left>0.25in</Left>
            <Height>0.75in</Height>
            <Width>3in</Width>
            <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
          </Tablix>
        </ReportItems>
        <Height>4.52083in</Height>
      </Body>
      <Width>7.5in</Width>
      <Page>
        <InteractiveHeight>0in</InteractiveHeight>
        <InteractiveWidth>0in</InteractiveWidth>
        <Style />
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>4</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>2</NumberOfRows>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportServerUrl></rd:ReportServerUrl>
  <rd:ReportID>427a9b7a-0570-45e3-912e-f62036630d2a</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Comment: I've never heard of anything like this before. If you had not said that you had not other expressions in te report then I would have thought you had set the format property to an expression as well as the backgroundcolor property. Assuming that is not the case then it might be easier to do this in the dataset query (set an indicator fields on each row to control the backgroundcolor property) rather than doing it in SSRS.

Comment: That's a good point, I should probably be doing it in the query anyway. At this point I'm wondering if it's just something off with my environment, nothing else seems to make sense. I added the code for a sample report, if anyone feels like trying it out. It would be interesting if it's reproducible.

Comment: I'll give this a go but you did not mention if this happened in design, once deployed or both and if it happens in design, what are you using  (Visual Studio, Report Builder) etc and version of the app?

Comment: Appreciate it. For reference, I am using Report Builder, and I received these results both in the design preview as well as deployed, on SSRS 2016. I'm not sure if I have a quick/easy way available to me to access 2017 or 2019, so I'm not sure if this will have the same behavior on those versions or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, only my findings...

I recreated your report and got the same results as you did.
I then tried various things on the lookup to see what happened (such as converting everything to text in the first two arguments) but this had no effect.

I then tried changing another column and removed the formatting from the original column and still it failed.

After some trial and error it looks like if you have a `LOOKUP()` that refences the same dataset **anywhere** on the row then it shows this issue.

To test this, add a new column to the second tablix (the working one) and set the **Value** expression to the be the return value of your lookup.

i.e.

```
=Lookup(
        (-1 * Fields!Balance.Value) & Fields!CustomerID.Value
        , Fields!Balance.Value & Fields!CustomerID.Value
        , Fields!Balance.Value
        ,"BalancesDS"
        )
```

You will see that the original column is still affected and the return value is returning the data as if it was the data on as shown rather than as it is in the dataset.

I can't help but think that this is something to do with the way `LOOKUP()` works and that you don't always have unique values but it is strange behaviour and personally I would think it's worth reporting to MS as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I think what really bothers me about this potential bug is that it isn't completely consistent - at least from this small test, it only seems to occur when the "parent" row is adjacent to the lookup row in the dataset. I would have an easier time accepting this behavior if it it also occurred for customer 3, but the inconsistency is what strikes me as really strange. I'll probably try to see if I can test on 2017 or above to see if this still occurs and then look into reporting to Microsoft.

Comment: I tested on 2016 and 2019 and get the same results. This also got my old brain working - I had a bug using `LOOKUP()` years ago that was never really resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335084/ssrs-lookup-function-bug

Comment: And I just realised **you** replied to my question! Small World! But it does seem to indicate that there is a bug if a lookup cannot find a unique value/

Comment: Oh haha wow! I didn't remember that at all. And looking through that question again, it looks like using `LookupSet` could kind of help in that situation, so I tried it out here - instead of `IIf(IsNothing(Lookup(...)))`, I tried `IIf(LookupSet(...).Length = 0, "No Color", "Yellow")`. But in this situation, this has the same result as `Lookup`, so no dice.

I guess my takeaway from all of this is that `Lookup` can be a bit unpredictable and should probably be avoided wherever possible.