# SSRS tablix with nested groups shows the last row of dataset as first row of first group on the first page of PDF report (but not the viewer)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a large tablix (Tablix1) with only two cells (top cell for header data, bottom for details).
The entire tablix is grouped on dataset field "ParentCode". Header cell shows information about the ParentCode and details cell has a tablix (Tablix2) that shows tabular data about ParentCode.

Issue: The first row of the first ParentCode that appears on the first page = last row of the whole dataset.

I added a dummy table above Tablix1 to push it on the second page and the issue disappears. (This was just something I was trying and not for the report.) Also, issue only happens in PDF export and Print Layout mode of SSRS Report Builder and not the regular report viewer. Issue also doesn't happen when there is only one ParentCode in the dataset i.e. only one overall group.

Anyone seen something like this happening? [image]

Comment: I did see odd behaviour, that although not the same as what you are seeing, was inexplicable and re-building the report from scratch on another PC fixed the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335084/ssrs-lookup-function-bug

 It's odd that you only see this when exporting. Have you deployed the report? Does it still do the same from the server?

Comment: @AlanSchofield Even after deploying, the issue persists only when exporting to PDF or printing.

Anyways, the issue in my case turned out to be the use of Lookup function in the last row of the grid. Removing Lookup function solved the problem.

Comment: It was the `LOOKUP()` function that caused my issue in the post I linked above years ago. There's obviously some bug related to that function  but it seems hard to reproduce.